# Alternative to 'head' that doesn't exit?

Tags: head

I need a utility that will print the first n lines, but then continue to run, sucking up the rest of the lines, but not printing them. I use it to not overwhelm the terminal with the output of a process that needs to continue to run (it writes results to a file).

I figured I can do `process | {head -n 100; cat > /dev/null}`, but is there something more elegant?

Comment: The process will continue after head, it just won't print anymore to the terminal.

Comment: What problem are you _actually_ trying to solve?

Comment: What do you mean to suck them?  If you just pipe to head, then the remaining output will be dismissed.

Comment: @JuliePelletier and stdout will be closed and well-written programs (those that only write to stdout, anyway) will notice that and terminate early.

Comment: @cas `trap '' PIPE`

Comment: @123 It may or may not, depending on whether or not the process has a bug. Some programs check for errors when writing to standard output and abort if they detect one. This is sane if, *and only if*, it is always an error to discard this output. Clearly, the OP is in a case where it is not an error to discard this output. Sadly, some programs do have precisely this bug, and a hack is needed to work around it.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

To continue "sucking up" the output from `process` while only *printing* the first 100 (or whatever) lines:

```
process | awk 'NR<=100'
```

Or:

```
process | sed -n '1,100p'
```

Comment: I usually just use `... | tee /dev/null | head ...`

Comment: @DavidSchwartz yep - it's what I'd do. Far more preferrable, since you can also dump all the output in a file and examine it at a later point in time. You never know when that's going to be needed - at worse, you have a file sitting around which you occasionally overwrite, at best, you can use it as a log to analyse what/why happened.